# How do I only select values from one row in tsv file?

Tags: csv, snakemake

*Edit: 
I should add that this question is basically exactly what I'm asking about: [How to use list in Snakemake Tabular configuration, for describing of sequencing units for bioinformatic pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54400171/how-to-use-list-in-snakemake-tabular-configuration-for-describing-of-sequencing)

The issue is that when I try to adapt it to my Snakefile I get an error message saying `'function' object has no attribute 'unique'` referring to the following line: `samples= list(units_table.SampleSM.unique())`

And in the same thread Johannes links to his gatk pipeline that also uses tsv files for this purpose, but I frankly don't understand what's going on so unfortunately it doesn't help. If I could get some input on my Snakefile below I'd be grateful.*

I need to start my workflow by populating variables based on a tsv file like this:

```
flowcell    sample  library lane    R1  R2
FlowCellX   SAMPLE1 libZ    L001    fastq/FCX/Sample1_L001.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/FCX/Sample1_L001.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellX   SAMPLE1 libZ    L002    fastq/FCX/Sample1_L002.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/FCX/Sample1_L002.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellX   SAMPLE2 libZ    L001    fastq/FCX/Sample2_L001.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/FCX/Sample2_L001.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellX   SAMPLE2 libZ    L002    fastq/FCX/Sample2_L002.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/FCX/Sample2_L002.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellY   SAMPLE1 libX    L001    fastq/FCY/Sample1_L001.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/FCY/Sample1_L001.R2.fastq.gz
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make it only select values from one row per pair of files, the reason is that I need to construct a read group by selecting values from all columns except for R1 and R2.

The only thing I can make it do currently is to combine every entry from every row and column in flowcell, sample, library and and lane, but I just want it to select the entries on one row per pair of input files.

Here's my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from snakemake.utils import validate, min_version

samples = pd.read_table("samples.tsv", sep='\t', dtype=str).set_index(["flowcell", "sample"], drop=False)

samples.index = samples.index.set_levels([i.astype(str) for i in samples.index.levels])  # enforce str in index


def get_fastq1(wildcards):
    return samples.loc[(wildcards.flowcell, wildcards.sample), ["R1"]].dropna()
def get_fastq2(wildcards):
    return samples.loc[(wildcards.flowcell, wildcards.sample), ["R2"]].dropna()

rule all:
    input:
        expand("Outputs/BwaMem/{sample}_{lane}_{flowcell}.mapped.bam", sample=samples['sample'], lane=samples['lane'], flowcell=samples['flowcell']),

rule BwaMem:
    input:
        fasta = "/references/Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta",
        fastq1 = get_fastq1,
        fastq2 = get_fastq2,
    params:
        rgs = repr('@RG:\tID:{flowcell}.{lane}\tSM:{sample}\tLB:PlaceHolder\tPU:{flowcell}.{lane}.{sample}\tPL:Illumina')
    output:
        "Outputs/BwaMem/{sample}_{lane}_{flowcell}.mapped.bam",
    shell:
        "bwa mem -M -t 12 {input.fasta} \
        -R {params.rgs} \
        {input.fastq1} \
        {input.fastq2} | \
        samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```

This works if I only have one row in the tsv file, but when I add a second row so I have a tsv file like this:

```
flowcell    sample  library lane    R1  R2
FlowCellX   SAMPLE1 libZ    L001    fastq/Sample1_L001.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/Sample1_L001.R2.fastq.gz
FlowCellY   SAMPLE2 libZ    L002    fastq/Sample2_L002.R1.fastq.gz  fastq/Sample2_L00.R2.fastq.gz
```

It gives me this error message:

```
InputFunctionException in line 18 of /home/oskar/01-workspace/00-temp/GVP/Snakefile:
KeyError: 9
Wildcards:
sample=SAMPLE1
lane=L001
flowcell=FlowCellY
```

It's trying to combine SAMPLE1 and L001 with FlowCellY and that's not what I want, I want it to only select `FlowCellX`, `SAMPLE1` and `L001` for the `fastq/FCX/Sample1_L001.R1.fastq.gz` and `fastq/FCX/Sample1_L001.R2.fastq.gz` input files. The resulting output file and read group would look like this:
Output file name:

```
SAMPLE1_FlowCellX_L001.mapped.bam
```

Read group:

```
@RG: ID:FlowCellX.L001 SM:SAMPLE1 LB:PlaceHolder PU:FlowCellX.L001.SAMPLE1 PL:Illumina
```

What am I missing?

And a second issue is that I have no clue how to add a `{library}` variable to the read group where the `..LB:PlaceHolder\t` is. If I try putting this variable in the `expand("Outputs/BwaMem/{sample}_{lane}_{flowcell}.mapped.bam", sample=samples['sample'], lane=samples['lane'], flowcell=samples['flowcell']),` line it expects `{library}` to be in the file name and that's not what I want. I guess this issue could be solved along with the solution to the previous answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One issue is that your `expand` function in `rule all` is going to create all the combinations of sample, lane and flowcell which results in invalid queries to the sample sheet (and probably it's not what you want). If you put `expand(...)` in a variable and print it you would see the resulting list. The fix below uses `zip` function to join sample, lane and flowcell in a parallel way.

Abut the `{library}` question, you could have a `get_RG` function similar to the `get_fastq` functions to return the appropropriate value from the sample sheet given the wildcards. See below, there may be better solutions but this hopefully puts you in the right direction...

```
import pandas as pd

samples = pd.read_csv("samples.tsv", sep='\t', dtype=str).set_index(["flowcell", "sample", "lane"], drop=False)

samples.index = samples.index.set_levels([i.astype(str) for i in samples.index.levels])  # enforce str in index

def get_fastq1(wildcards):
    return samples.loc[(wildcards.flowcell, wildcards.sample, wildcards.lane), ["R1"]].dropna()

def get_fastq2(wildcards):
    return samples.loc[(wildcards.flowcell, wildcards.sample, wildcards.lane), ["R2"]].dropna()

def get_RG(wc):
    library= samples.loc[(wc.flowcell, wc.sample, wc.lane), ["library"]].unique()[0]
    rgs = r'@RG:\tID:%(flowcell)s.%(lane)s\tSM:%(sample)s\tLB:%(library)s\tPU:%(flowcell)s.%(lane)s.%(sample)s\tPL:Illumina' \
        % {'flowcell': wc.flowcell, 
           'lane': wc.lane, 
           'sample': wc.sample, 
           'library': library}
    return rgs    

rule all:
    input:
        expand("Outputs/BwaMem/{sample}_{lane}_{flowcell}.mapped.bam", zip,
            sample=samples['sample'], lane=samples['lane'],
            flowcell=samples['flowcell']),

rule BwaMem:
    input:
        fasta = "Homo_sapiens_assembly38.fasta",
        fastq1 = get_fastq1,
        fastq2 = get_fastq2,
    params:
        rgs= get_RG,
    output:
        "Outputs/BwaMem/{sample}_{lane}_{flowcell}.mapped.bam",
    shell:
        r"bwa mem -M -t 12 {input.fasta} \
            -R '{params.rgs}' \
            {input.fastq1} \
            {input.fastq2} \
        | samtools view -Sb - > {output}"
```